# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to do form binding in `angular 4`. Below is my code.
**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.form = new FormGroup({
        firstname: new FormControl('First Name'),
        lastname: new FormControl(''),
        languages: new FormControl('')
      });
    }

  onSubmit = function(user) {
    console.log(user);
  };
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { MemberComponent } from './member/member.component';
import { ItemListComponent } from './item-list/item-list.component';
import { SortPipe } from './app.sort';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SortPipe,
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    MemberComponent,
    ItemListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [FormGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" name="firstname" formControlName="firstname" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="lastname" name="lastname" formControlName="lastname" />
    <br>
    <select name="languages" formControlName="languages">
        <option value="C++">C++</option>
        <option value="Java">Java</option>
        <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

But I am getting the following error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
>       
>    -->
>   ][FormGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
>       )
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.es5.js:26882)
>       at compiler.es5.js:26769
>       at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1679)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26768)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26697)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have mistyped.

It should be **f**ormGroup instead of **F**ormGroup:

```typescript
<form [formGroup]="form"
```

because `FormGroupDirective` looks like:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[formGroup]', 
  ...
})
export class FormGroupDirective extends ControlContainer implements Form,
```

Comment: can give me a full example?